# Select all elements with overflow-y=scroll not working

Tags: css, sass

Good day

I am trying to do something that should be simple, but not having much luck. I want to select all elements with the following CSS property and value:

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

Here is what I have tried based on two separate and conflicting W3Schools articles:

```
*[overflow-y=scroll] {
  background-color: red;
}

*[overflow-y="scroll"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Articles in question being these:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here, please? I'd greatly appreciate any advice

Comment: That does not work. You need to use javascript.

Comment: Put your html code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the articles you linked, CSS searches through HTML attributes, not CSS properties. So you can use square brackets to search in HTML attributes like this:

```
#input[type="number"] {
    background-color: red;
}

<input type="number" placeholder="Enter your age">
```

But unfortunately you can't access CSS properties in the same way.

### Solution 1: CSS

Assuming that you set `overflow-y` with CSS, you can use same selectors to set the `background-color`. For example:

```
.scrollCont {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: red;
}
```

### Solution 2: JS

You can loop through elements and check if the `overflow-y` has value of `scroll`.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].forEach(elem => {
    if (getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("overflow-y") == "scroll")
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```